# How to Join 2 different variables in Pig?

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, concatenation

I am a total newbie to pig and I have written the following pig script:

```
DEFINE format `format_text.py $EMOJI $ACRONYM` SHIP ('$STREAM_FILE_PATH/format_text.py');

DEFINE parse `parse.sh` SHIP ('$STREAM_FILE_PATH_SYNTAXNET/parse.sh');

DEFINE process_roots `process_roots.py` SHIP ('$STREAM_FILE_PATH_SYNTAXNET/process_roots.py');

input_data = LOAD '$DATA_INPUT';

result1 = STREAM input_data THROUGH format;
result2 = STREAM result1 THROUGH parse;
result3 = STREAM result2 THROUGH process_roots;

result4 = foreach result1 Generate CONCAT (result1, result3);

STORE result1 into '$DATA_OUTPUT';
STORE result2 into '$SYNTAXNET_OUTPUT';
STORE result4 into '$SYNTAXNET_RESULTS';
```

So, my `input_data` is a json file of a tweet.

1. `format` formats the "text" field of the json to clean the tweet.
2. `parse` runs the cleaned json through syntaxnet to generate dependency relations. The output `result2` looks something like:

`2       Bank    _       NOUN    NNP     _       3       nn      _       _`

for each word of the tweet (where second column is the word).

3. `process_roots` does some more processing on `result2` and generates `result3` which is a json field that looks like:

`avl_tags_syntaxnet: [{'pos_tag': 'NNP', 'position': '1', 'dep_rel': 'nn', 'parent': '3', 'word': 'US'}, ....................... {'pos_tag': '.', 'position': '30', 'dep_rel': 'punct', 'parent': '23', 'word': '...'}]`

Now, all I want to do is append the newly created Json field (`result3`) to `result1` and store it somewhere. I read about `CONCAT` in pig and wrote this code for `result4` in the pig script but it throws an error. Please tell me what is the right way to do it.

Comment: Where is your result relation? result4 = foreach result Generate CONCAT (result, result2);CONCAT is used on string type so you will to use it like CONCAT((chararray)result3.$0,(chararray)result1.$0)

Comment: Extremely sorry for the typos. there is no result atall. It should have been result1 instead of result. i changed the variables names but forgot to change it everywhere. I edited the question now. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Could you please elaborate on what the $ sumbols are for? Thanks!

Comment: @cricket_007 it throws syntax errors.

Comment: The $ symbols are references to indices within the tuples.

Comment: You cannot concat relations.result1 and result3 are relations.In order to reference the fields in the relation,you need to access fields using the $,similar to indices in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation is for fields, however you are trying to combine multiple aliases.

The way to combine aliases is with a **join**.

---

Based on how your code is structured, use (or add) a unique identifier for each line that remains intact during the various operations. Then in the final phase join all of them together.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. So now I have 2 results `result1` and `result2` (both jsons) with a common field named `avl_lexicon_text`. Can you please tell me how to perform a `JOIN` on these two now?